# No module error after docker-compose up with Python package from git

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip

I have a problem with install python package (I will call this `'GITPACKAGENAME'`) from gitlab after running `docker-compose up app`.

Here is an example error log:

```
...
app_1        | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GITPACKAGENAME'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile /app
COPY Pipfile.lock /app
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system

CMD python ./src/main.py
```

part of **docker-compose.yml**

```
...
services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: python ./src/main.py
    volumes:
      - .:/app
...
```

part of **Pipfile**:

```
[packages]
...
GITPACKAGENAME = {editable = true,git = "https://LOGIN:PASSWORD@gitlab/path/to/GITPACKAGENAME.git",ref = "develop"}
...
```

Also I tried to install package using pip, for example I added to **Dockerfile**:

```
...
RUN pip install git+https://LOGIN:PASSWORD@gitlab/path/to/GITPACKAGENAME.git@develop#egg=GITPACKAGENAME
...
```

I got the same error.

After this I tried cloning repo using **Dockerfile** commands:

```
...
RUN git clone https://LOGIN:PASSWORD@gitlab/path/to/GITPACKAGENAME.git
RUN git checkout develop
...
```

aaaaand I got same :'))

Every time I checked GITPACKAGENAME package in container bash using `docker-compose run app /bin/bash`, checked `pip list` and checked `WORKDIR`.

I have next staff:

```
Docker version 19.03.8-ce, build afacb8b7f0
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown

  Operating System: Arch Linux
            Kernel: Linux 5.6.11-arch1-1
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Hello, were you able to execute the pipenv install outside Docker? If yes and success did Pipfile.lock has reference of `your git`?

Comment: This is just a side note, but you don't need the `COPY Pipfile /app` and `COPY Pipfile.lock /app` lines in your Dockerfile because you've already copied over the whole directory (`COPY . /app`).

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem [in this repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-idmitryz) but it all seems to Just Work.

Comment: @larsks, thanks for help. I did a pull request with `docker-compose.yml` in your repo. Try this, please.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

When you run `pipenv install --system --deploy`, the `pipenv` command installs your modules into `src/<modulename>`. When you bind-mount your local directory on top of `/app`, you mask the underlying files so the module is no longer available.

If you want to keep my bind mount, you can restructure things like this:

- Stop installing your module from git with `editable = True`.
- This means you can't install with `--system` anymore, which means
- You probably want to use `pipenv run` in your Dockerfile.

In other words, modify your Pipfile so that it looks like this:

```
[packages]
...
GITPACKAGENAME = {git = "https://LOGIN:PASSWORD@gitlab/path/to/GITPACKAGENAME.git",ref = "develop"}
...
```

And make your Dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install pipenv

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pipenv install --deploy

CMD pipenv run python ./src/main.py
```

With those changes, I'm able to run something that looks like your `docker-compose.yml` file.

---

**Update**

This also works fine if I just use `pip` instead of `pipenv`.  That is, if I have a `requirements.txt` that looks like this:

```
git+https://example.com/my/module
```

And a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python ./src/main.py
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` works just fine, because `pip` doesn't require any store in the local directory, so the fact that you're masking it with a bind mount at runtime doesn't cause an issue.

(You can find my complete test in the [using-pip branch](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-idmitryz/tree/using-pip) of that example repository.)

Comment: I need pipenv only for installation of dependencies in docker container. I don't need virtualenv inside another "dockerenv". I also tried using `pip install -r requirements.txt` with git repo and got same error.

Comment: I think the changes I've suggested here allow your code to run without error. If there's some aspect of this solution that is causing a problem, let me know and I'll see what I can do.